# Why can't I see my drives

Tags: hard-drive

[image]

I want to download something and when I want to change the directory to save it in another drive I cant see my drives, even when they are mounted

Comment: You have to go to the folder where the drives are mounted, `/media` or `/mnt`. Start by clicking "Computer" ;)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: it's ubuntu 19.04